# Is there a Java 8 implementation of a random generator supporting NIST standards?

Tags: java, android, security, random, java-8

I am trying to securely generate random numbers. It must support NIST standards, that is NIST SP 800-90A, SP 800-90B, SP 800-90C. I've [read](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/273) that Java 9 has an implementation of `SecureRandom` supporting such standards.

My question is: is there an implementation supporting these standards in Java 8 (I am using Android)? Ideally I would like it to be built-in but otherwise what would you advise?

Comment: Seems that Java 8 also has SecureRandom: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Comment: Yes but as mentionned here https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/273 it is not supporting NIST standards

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, what's stopping you from using Java 9?

Comment: @Sebastiaan van den Broek I do not have the hand on the Java version of the project I am working on (medical device).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading ["The Bouncy Castle FIPS Java API in 100 Examples"](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BCFipsIn100.pdf) by David Hook (page 12) correctly, the FIPS release of Bouncy Castle provides implementations of the 3 DRBGs described in NIST SP 800-90A.

You can find more information about the Bouncy Castle Java FIPs project [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/).

Other FIPS certified JCSE provider implementations may also support this.  (I have not investigated ...)